# twitter bootstrap, stop images overlapping text?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

Hi all using twitters bootstrap: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables

I am wandering how I can stop this happening: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/6606/screenshotfrom201306071.png I want the image to just bump up above the text as it would do if you kept making the window smaller.

Link for it: http://www.prxa.info/articles/category/1
User: test.prxa.
pass: test

I NEED images to have a max of 350px here as some images people include are massive and have to be resized to not mess it all up.

Here is my custom css for the thumbnail area and the images inside:

```
.thumbnail
{
    width: 350px;
    height: 220px;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img.tagline-img
{
    max-width: 350px;
    max-height: 220px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with chrome and inspector to nix the width in the img.tagline-img without touching .thumbnail, and that seemed to avoid overflow into the right column.

```
img.tagline-img {
    /*max-width: 350px;*/
    max-height: 220px;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in firefox, i also need max-width in as some might link to a stupidly big image.